# speeding up csv data access in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I have imported a csv file, it has 1050 rows for each product usage column

```
parsed_csv["PRODUCTUSAGE_#{x}_BRAND_#{@brand_no}"]
```

my problem is the following, each access to a row of data:

```
parsed_csv["PRODUCTUSAGE_1_BRAND_1"][0]
```

takes 0.05 seconds, this is incredibly slow, especially when trying to evaluate 1050 rows... Is there a more efficient way of dealing with this? I tried to speed up my computations on matrix data like this by using threads, but thanks to Ruby's Global Interpreter Lock, this was a dead end...

Comment: Try to create a hash from your array: `parsed_csv_hash[:productusage][:brand_no]` and then work with it.